# Create a jax-ws client where the message will pass in parent and child form

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

we are creating a web service client for our client. which sends the request to third party and third party register that client in the CRM. The soap message is creating as per parent and child node basis in the following manner.

```
<Claim>
   <Client_SSN_No>123</Client_SSN_No>
   <Other_Detail>
      <Address> </Address>
      <Phone_No> </Phone_No>
   </Other_Detail>
</Claim>
```

In the above example the Client_SSN_No is passed successfully using getter and setter but if we try to create the message for Other_Detail tag if pass without other_details. like this

```
<Claim>
   <Client_SSN_No>123</Client_SSN_No>
   <Other_Detail>        </Other_Detail>
   <Address> </Address>
   <Phone_No> </Phone_No>
</Claim>
```

Following is my code that invoke the web service.

```
public java.lang.String consultaXmlStub(BPAval.ParametrosConsultaDTO parametrosConsulta) throws java.rmi.RemoteException
{
    org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
    _call.setOperation(_operations[2]);
    _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
    _call.setSOAPActionURI("");
    _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
    _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://XYZ", "RegisterClient"));
    _call.setTargetEndpointAddress(locator);

    setRequestHeaders(_call);
    setAttachments(_call);
    try
    {
        java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {parametrosConsulta});
        if (_resp instanceof java.rmi.RemoteException)
        {
            throw (java.rmi.RemoteException)_resp;

        }
        else
        {
            extractAttachments(_call);
            try
            {
                return (java.lang.String) _resp;
            }
            catch (java.lang.Exception _exception)
            {
                return (java.lang.String) org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils.convert(_resp, java.lang.String.class);
            }
        }
  }
  catch (org.apache.axis.AxisFault axisFaultException)
  {
    System.out.println(axisFaultException.toString());
    throw axisFaultException;
  }
}
```

Comment: You use axis framework, not jax-ws.

Comment: Have you checked if your request xml conforms to the xsd that you and the third party service agreed upon? Maybe the `Address` and `Phone_No` tags are expected to be within the `Other_Detail` tag and not outside.

Comment: This is a kind of an example that I have given above. The structure of message is same.